# XML Schema key/keyref where keyref is not an attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

i am writing an XML Schema to verify XML documents.

If a node references a key by having the id of the referenced node as an ATTRIBUTE, i can enforce the constraint, like so.

```
<root>
  <A>
    <as id="1"/>
    <as id="2"/>
  </A>
  <B>
    <bs refthisid="1"/>
    <bs refthisid="2"/>
    <bs refthisid="3"/> /* would give an error during validation */
  </B>
</root>
```

I do this via the `<xs:key>` and `<xs:keyref>` elements in XML Schema. Like so:

```
<xs:key name="some_key">
    <xs:selector xpath="root/A/as">
    <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
</xs:key>
<xs:keyref name="some_keyref" refer="some_key">
    <xs:selector xpath="root/B/bs">
    <xs:field xpath="@refthisid"/>
</xs:keyref>
```

That works fine, but what do i do if the refkey is the VALUE/TEXT of a node? Like so:

```
    <root>
      <A>
        <as id="1"/>
        <as id="2"/>
      </A>
      <B>
        <bs>1</bs>
        <bs>2</bs>
        <bs>3></bs> /* should give an error during validation */
      </B>
    </root>
```

I can't figure out what to put in the selector and field paths. :-(

```
<xs:keyref name="some_keyref" refer="some_key">
    <xs:selector xpath="root/B/bs??????">
    <xs:field xpath="??????"/>
</xs:keyref>
```

Or is a completely differnet approach neccessary?
XML is not really my strength and my online search resulted in absolutely no usable suggestions.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried just `root/B/bs`?

Comment: Yep, i tried. However, what do i put inside the xs:field xpath? If i leave it empty, my validator complains. :-(

Comment: @Lazarus536 Simply `.`.

Comment: OMG. It works. I must be stupid obviously. :-) Thank you!